# CodeIgniter unknown SQL error

Tags: database, codeigniter

Here is my selection code from db:

```
$q = $this->db->like('Autor1' or 'Autor2' or 'Autor3' or 'Autor4', $vyraz)
    ->where('stav', 1)
    ->order_by('id', 'desc')
    ->limit($limit)
    ->offset($offset)
    ->get('knihy');
                    
    return $q->result();
```

Where `$vyraz = "Zuzana Šidlíková";`

And the error is:

> Nastala chyba databĂˇzy
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'
>
> `SELECT * FROM (\`knihy`) WHERE `stav` = 1 AND `1` LIKE '%Zuzana Ĺ idlĂ­kovĂˇ%' ORDER BY `id` desc LIMIT 9
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\artbooks\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for what you're trying to do, but still technically valid, because this:

```
'Autor1' or 'Autor2' or 'Autor3' or 'Autor4'
```

...is actually a valid PHP expression which evaluates to `TRUE` (because all non-empty strings are "truthy"), which when cast to a string or `echo`ed comes out as `1`, so the DB class is looking to match on a column called "1".

[Example:](http://codepad.org/2eMcbbgC)

```
function like($arg1, $arg2)
{
    return "WHERE $arg1 LIKE '%$arg2%'";
}

$vyraz = 'Zuzana Šidlíková';
echo like('Autor1' or 'Autor2' or 'Autor3' or 'Autor4', $vyraz);

// Output: WHERE 1 LIKE '%Zuzana Šidlíková%'
```

Anyways, here's what you need:

```
$q = $this->db
    ->like('Autor1', $vyraz)
    ->or_like('Autor2', $vyraz)
    ->or_like('Autor3', $vyraz)
    ->or_like('Autor4', $vyraz)
    ->where('stav', 1)
    ->order_by('id', 'desc')
    ->limit($limit)
    ->offset($offset)
    ->get('knihy');
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? More information - as much as possible. Same error message? Not producing the query you want? Not returning results you expect? Exactly what do you mean?

Comment: I see no reason why that would be true, are you 100% sure you aren't just running your original code again? Try commenting out parts of it to see where the problem comes from. Do you understand the error I pointed out?

Comment: I am absolutely sure that I run your new code. I tried it with die(); adding die(); on different position unlit error disappeared and problem is in querry

Comment: I can't understand why this code would produce the same exact query as your original broken/invalid code. What *specifically* was the part you commented out that got the error to disappear?

Comment: You was right I have problem in different part of code :) THANKS A LOT! :)